# how to get user's skype status

Tags: service, status, skype

i'm developing an android application that will send notifications to users, one of the ways it notify is via skype, i need to know the user's status to trust that the user is going to read the message since it seems i can send skype messages even when the target user is offline.

im using https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/connector/ bot's API to send the messages

¿is there anyway to get the current status(online, away, etc..) of an especific skype user?

since it seems they no longer offer "mystatus.skype.com" service.

Comment: You can't "trust" the user to read the messages, what if they are online but AFK?

Comment: in theory if they are AFK their status should be "away" but yeah there will be scenarios when even if the user is online the user is not going to read the message right away, i just want to remove the scenario where i know there is 100% chance the user is not going to read the message (when he is offline or away), if the user is offline i would use another mean of comunication like SMS