# Get user online status in Skype

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper, skype4py

Is there any tools, services or APIs that allow you to get online statuses of some users in Skype? I searched, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259133/how-to-get-users-skype-status?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968726/is-it-still-possible-to-get-skypes-user-online-status?rq=1

Comment: javascript sample here - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/js-skype-status, but requires skype online, not on-premise or hybrid. This Stack Q looks like follows the same path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293834/get-skype-for-business-presence-status-programmatically